# Is 109 not more than 10? I can't answer protected questions!

Tags: support, reputation

I recently found a question where I knew a small little software library that would've allowed me to answer a question. When I went to answer this, I encountered this:

[image]

Of course, the question was protected by the Community user, which ups the requirement that is needed to post an answer. However, I've got 109 reputation (I've posted one question, and one answer (+1/-1) so I shouldn't be banned for anything), but I can't answer the question.

I assume this is a bug. What's going on?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protected-questions+faq

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The protection system requires 10 rep *earned on the site* - meaning the association bonus doesn't count. As far as the protection system is concerned, you only have 8 rep here.

Comment: Ah. Interesting. I've never really seem to find anything stating this, but it is what it is :)

Comment: @Zizouz212 Yupp. And though I'm sure we had this topic before (and I know the answer), I cannot find it. But it comes up sooner or later on every SE site. Ah, here's the one I've remembered: [Why can't I answer a question](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/914/16575), and [Why can't I answer a protected question?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/1681/16575) Btw: Similar thing would happen if you really had 100 rep *earned on this site*, but then offered a bounty (reputation drop).